# Ruby - Can I import a gem under an alias to avoid dependency issues?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby, and am working on a project that has a `Gemfile` like so:

#### Gemfile

```
require_relative 'gem_source_url'
gem_source_url = GemSourceUrl.get_source_url

source gem_source_url do
  gem 'jwt'
  gem 'some_other_lib'
end
```

My problem is that the gem `some_other_lib`, includes a version of `jwt` that is too old (1.5.6), and I can't use, but I can't change anything to do with that gem.

Can I somehow import a newer version of `jwt` gem under an alias (2.1.0), so I can use the newer version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use 2 versions of gem at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333645/use-2-versions-of-gem-at-same-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely not really possible without some dirty code since importing two versions of the same gem would mean that in practice you would be using two versions of the same class (JWT in this case). A better approach would be to ask the makers of `some_other_lib` to update their dependencies or, if it's no longer being maintained, fork and update yourself and then put out the updated version for the benefit of the community.

Edit: For more info on the conflicting classes, see [Use 2 versions of gem at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333645/use-2-versions-of-gem-at-same-time?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)